# Where in this code that when I change the format it will throw that error in the else statement within the Set Function?

Tags: javascript, properties, get, set, accessor

The tutorial says if the full name is not in the correct format i.e., first name, space, and last name,  it will throw an error.

```
let person = {
firstName: 'John',
lastName: 'Doe'
}



Object.defineProperty(person, 'fullName', {
get: function () {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
},
set: function (value) {
    let parts = value.split(' ');
    if (parts.length == 2) {
        this.firstName = parts[0];
        this.lastName = parts[1];
    } else {
        throw 'Invalid name format';
    }
}


console.log(person.fullName);
```

This code will display in the console:

```
John Doe
```

I am really trying to understand the code, but how the set function will throw these 'Invalid name format', in the else statement?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. What is the _specific, complete_ error that you are getting? "An error" isn't very helpful.

Comment: Hi How I can reopen this question? I already point out the problem.

Comment: It automatically goes into a "repoen" queue where high-reputation users can vote to reopen it every time it gets edited. Editing to improve the question is the best way to have it reopened. Though... I'm still not clear what you're asking. Are you asking how `if` and `else` work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uhm, Here?

```
else {
 throw 'Invalid name format';
}
```

I kinda don't get it, is that what you were asking for?

Comment: Yes, that throw statement.

Comment: That only i am asking, just for me to fully understand the code, as I am a beginner in Javascript